# Is all DDR3 1333MHz RAM PC3-10600?

Tags: memory

As the title suggests I'm looking for some more RAM for my laptop. The exact specifications on the RAM are:

4GB 2Rx8 PC3-10600S-09-10-F2

My local PC store sells 1333MHz laptop RAM which google suggests is the same clock speed as the above. Will any brand of that clock speed RAM match the above?

Comment: DDR3 1333 is also called PC3 10600 (due to rounding, it's also 10660 or 10666 or sometimes even 10700).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_modules

Comment: an interesting question is what is the part after the 10600 "10600S-09-10-F2 " http://www.amazon.co.uk/Notebook-Ram-Samsung-M471B5673FH0-CH9-PC3-10600S-09-10-F2/dp/B005PSA9L2

Comment: you are asking two questions here. a)is DDR3 1333MHz = PC3 10600  b)Will any brand of that clock speed RAM match 4GB 2Rx8 PC3-10600S-09-10-F2